# Unknown column '0' in 'field list' - Knex.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, knex.js

I have `Knex.js` code, which is works:

```
await knex('main_page_vouchers').del()
  .where('country_id', '=', region_id)
return knex('main_page_vouchers')
  .insert(result)
```

I'd like to change it a little bit and instead of 2 knex request, use only one, so I tried something like this:

```
return knex('main_page_vouchers')
   .where('country_id', '=', region_id)
   .update(result)
```

Seems like it has to do the same as first code does, but it doesn't, and I get an error:

```
  code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlState: '42S22',
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column '0' in 'field list'"
```

So, how can I make it using only 1 `knex` request (first request works)?

Comment: what does `result` contain? `console.log`

Comment: This is list of objects

Comment: According to the Knex docs - the .update() method expects key/Value pairs - or one object with key value pairs, not a list...

Comment: But it's weird, then why the first one works correctly? I have check `console.log`, and there was `index: 0` and I made `index: '0'`. Still that error

Comment: Just check with the Knex docs. The `.insert` method can accept arrays/list. The `.update` method cannot. The keys are the column names. So 0 is the array key, that is wrongly considered to be a column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.update(objOrAnArrayOfObjects)` and `.insert()` are different SQL operations.

Insert allows to insert multiple rows at once to database, thus `.insert()` allows passing an array of object to it.

`.update(obj)` updates single set of values to the rows that are matching `where` parts of the query. So passing an array of objects just doesn't work for updating.